# Execute a bash script in Unity Cloud Build

Tags: c#, android, bash, unity-game-engine, unity3d-cloud-build

My requirement is to execute a bash script "PostProcessShellScript.sh" in PostProcessBuild. Unity build runs fine, but build fails in Unity Cloud Build.

Below is my code :

```
public static void OnPostProcessBuild(BuildTarget target, string pathToBuiltProject) {
  .....
 string scriptPath = Application.dataPath + "/Plugins/Android/Editor/PostProcessShellScript.sh";

//Runs fine on Local Unity build
//RunInShell("C:\\Program Files\\bash.exe","/" + scriptPath + " " + " " + "/" + apkPath + "/"+ "/" + apkName, false);

 RunInShell("open","/" + scriptPath + " " + " " + "/" + apkPath + "/"+ "/" + apkName, false);
}

public static void RunInShell(string file, string args, bool waitForExit = true) {
    System.Diagnostics.Process ppScriptProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    ppScriptProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
    ppScriptProcess.StartInfo.FileName = file;
    ppScriptProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
    ppScriptProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    ppScriptProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    ppScriptProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    ppScriptProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    ppScriptProcess.Start ()
}
```

Error details on UCB :

> ! Unity player export failed!
>
> ! build of 'default_-android' failed. compile failed
>
> Publishing build 22 of surbhijain87/roll-a-ball-game for target
>   'default_-android'...
>
> publishing finished successfully.
>
> done.
>
> **Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure**
>
> postbuildstatus finished successfully.   Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

too implicit.

I am using the **shell scripting** to resolve the issues.

UCB running on mono and shell scripting looks like the way to go.

**Your resolution:** convert the code to a shell script and attach on the UCB config from the UI